# Adding a Row/Column from Text File

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

Basically the first row is 100 100 100 100 100, but I'm lost on how to actually read by each line and add them together to print to the screen.
The first column has 20  integers and I need to add them as well. I realize I need an array but do I need two arrays or just the original grid array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 5

int main() {

// Open the input file and read in the number of cases to process.
FILE* ifp;
FILE* marketOut;

ifp = fopen("marketing.txt", "r");
marketOut = fopen("marketing.out.txt", "w");

int loop, numCases;
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numCases);

// Go through each input case.
for (loop=0; loop<numCases; loop++)
{

// Get this input grid.
int grid[ROWS][COLS], i, j, x;
int a=0;
int nums[100];

x=0;


    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grid[i][j]);

    // Will store best value for row or column.
    int best = 0;

    while (i<ROWS)
        {
            x=grid[i]+i;

        }



    printf("x=%d", x);


    // Output result.
    printf("%d\n", best);
}

fclose(ifp);
fclose(marketOut);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your input file has 20 lines, and each line has five values.  It seems like you need to read in all 100 values, and store them.  Then go through in row order to get the best value for each row.  Last go through in column order to get the best value for each column.

Comment: You need a minimum 5 variables (or one 5 element array) to read each row into (or you can skip and just keep the sums). In addition you need one *sum* variable for each *sum* you want to keep. If I were summing all the rows and columns, I would use a 5-element array to hold values read from each row, and one 6-element array to hold all the sums (0-4 for the column sums, and element 5 for the row running row sum). You can do it in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you have a file [**marketing.txt**](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cop3223/labs/L07/marketing.txt) that has a single irrelevant value (at least to my understanding) on the first row, followed by `500-rows` containing `5-values` per row. The challenge is to compute various totals for each group of `20-lines` (`row` and `col` subtotals for each line and group) and finally `row` and `col` totals for the file, along with various other max/mins.

You are given some base file **marketing-scaffold.c** with a basic subset of the code you posted. In order to handle the data you are to fill/re-fill a 2D array and then compute the sums. I will leave the 2D array handling to you since that appears the jest of the project, but will help organizing the loop structure to handle the repetitive sums.

To begin, the 2D array isn't mandatory for computing the row/column sums. There you simply need to keep running totals for the 20-line block and the file overall. The row-sum for each line is simply the sum of each element in each row.

Reading the file, requires reading/discarding the first line (`fgets` makes as much sense as anything else). After discarding the first line, you will basically read five-integer values per-line, in groups of twenty, until `EOF` is encountered. For that you could do something similar to:

```
enum { NCOL = 5, NSUM, NROW = 20, MAXC = 256 };  /* constants */
...
    int idx = 0;                /* row index */
    ...
    for (;;) {                  /* for all 20 line blocks in file */
        int row[NCOL] = {0},                    /* row values     */
            n = NROW, rtn = 0;
            ...
        while (n-- && (rtn = fscanf (fp, " %d %d %d %d %d", &row[0], &row[1],
               &row[2], &row[3], &row[4])) == NCOL && rtn != EOF) {
            int rsum = 0;
            /* compute row/col sums
               ... */
            } /* output row values | row sum */
            printf (" row [%3d]     %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d  |  %3d\n",
                    idx++, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], rsum);
        }
        if (rtn == EOF) break;      /* if EOF, break outer loop */
    }
```

Looking though the code, the `enum` at global scope simply provides a way to declare multiple constants used through the remainder of your code. The outer `for (;;)` loop, just loops until it is broken. Within the outer-loop, the value `'n'` is set to `NROW` (`20`) and the `while` loop will execute at most `n` times or until `fscanf` fails to read `NCOL` (`5`) values or `EOF` is encountered. While the `while` loop will break on `EOF`, that does nothing to break the outer-loop, so the return of `fscanf` is captured in `rtn` and checked after the `while` loop exits. If `rtn` is `EOF`, the outer-loop exits.

That is one basic approach you can take to segment *marketing.txt* into 20-row groups. The remainder is storing the required sums so that 20-line subtotals can be computed as well as the file totals. While there are a number of ways to do this, you know you will need 1 total for each `column` as well as the total of each `row`. Simply reading the 5 values from each row will provide the values for the row sum. If you then just think in terms of *block-scope* and keep totals of each for each block of code (e.g. the code block for each loop between `{ ... }`), you then have the values, subtotals and totals you need.

The other thing to keep in mind is the resetting (or zeroing) the values for each set of values you keep each time the 20-line group of lines repeats. Simply declaring the relevant variables and initializing to `0` at the beginning of each individual block will do.

Putting the pieces together, using `tsum` for the file-total column and row sums, `idx` for the row index, `csum` for the 20-line row and column totals and reading the values from each row into the `row` array (along with a couple of simple counter variables), you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { NCOL = 5, NSUM, NROW = 20, MAXC = 256 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    int idx = 0, tsum[NSUM] = {0};  /* row index, total sum */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fgets (buf, MAXC, fp);       /* read/discard first line w/25  */

    for (;;) {                  /* for all 20 line blocks in file */
        int row[NCOL] = {0},                    /* row values     */
            csum[NSUM] = {0},                   /* col & row sums */
            i, n = NROW, rtn = 0, beg = idx;
        /* for each line in 20 line block, read values int row */
        while (n-- && (rtn = fscanf (fp, " %d %d %d %d %d", &row[0], &row[1],
            &row[2], &row[3], &row[4])) == NCOL && rtn != EOF) {
            int rsum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < NCOL; i++) { /* for each value in row */
                rsum += row[i];          /* compute row sum */
                csum[i] += row[i];       /* 20 line col sum */
                tsum[i] += row[i];       /* total col sum   */
            } /* output row values | row sum */
            printf (" row [%3d]     %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d  |  %3d\n",
                    idx++, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], rsum);
            csum[NCOL] += rsum;     /* 20 line row sum sub-total */
            tsum[NCOL] += rsum;     /* file row sum total */
        }
        if (rtn == EOF) break;      /* if EOF, break outer loop */

        printf ("-------------------------------------\n"); /* 20 ln sub-total */
        printf (" rows[%3d-%3d] %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d  |  %3d\n\n", beg, idx - 1,
                csum[0], csum[1], csum[2], csum[3], csum[4], csum[NCOL]);
    }
    printf ("=====================================\n");    /* file totals */
    printf ("  total  %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d  |  %3d\n",
            tsum[0], tsum[1], tsum[2], tsum[3], tsum[4], tsum[NCOL]);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

Giving the *marketing.txt* as the first argument (or just redirecting the contents to `stdin`), the code will read and sum the row values in 20-line groups and then give the file total, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/marketing_custom <dat/marketing.txt
 row [  0]     100 100 100 100 100  |  500
 row [  1]       1   1   2   1   2  |    7
 row [  2]       2   2   3   4   5  |   16
 row [  3]       3   5   5   3   3  |   19
 row [  4]       4   2   2   0   0  |    8
 row [  5]       5   0   0   2   2  |    9
 row [  6]       6   1   1   1   1  |   10
 row [  7]       7   4   3   2   1  |   17
 row [  8]       8   4   3   2   1  |   18
 row [  9]       9  10  10  10  10  |   49
 row [ 10]      10   4   5   4   2  |   25
 row [ 11]      11   4   3   2   1  |   21
 row [ 12]      12   1   2   3   4  |   22
 row [ 13]      13   4   3   2   1  |   23
 row [ 14]      14   4   3   2   1  |   24
 row [ 15]      15   1   2   3   4  |   25
 row [ 16]      16  13   3   4   4  |   40
 row [ 17]      17 100 100 100 182  |  499
 row [ 18]      18  17  18  19  20  |   92
 row [ 19]     228  13  14  15  16  |  286
-------------------------------------
 rows[  0- 19] 499 290 282 279 360  |  1710

 row [ 20]     100 100 100 100 100  |  500
 row [ 21]       1   1   2   1   2  |    7
 row [ 22]       2   2   3   4   5  |   16
 row [ 23]       3   5   5   3   3  |   19
 row [ 24]       4   2   2   0   0  |    8
 row [ 25]       5   0   0   2   2  |    9
 row [ 26]       6   1   1   1   1  |   10
 row [ 27]       7   4   3   2   1  |   17
 row [ 28]       8   4   3   2   1  |   18
 row [ 29]       9  10  10  10  10  |   49
 row [ 30]      10   4   5   4   2  |   25
 row [ 31]      11   4   3   2   1  |   21
 row [ 32]      12   1   2   3   4  |   22
 row [ 33]      13   4   3   2   1  |   23
 row [ 34]      14   4   3   2   1  |   24
 row [ 35]      15   1   2   3   4  |   25
 row [ 36]      16  13   3   4   4  |   40
 row [ 37]      17 100 100 100 182  |  499
 row [ 38]      18  17  18  19  20  |   92
 row [ 39]     230  13  14  15  16  |  288
-------------------------------------
 rows[ 20- 39] 501 290 282 279 360  |  1712

<snip>

 row [499]     100 100 100 100 100  |  500
-------------------------------------
 rows[480-499] 499 290 282 279 1251  |  2601

=====================================
  total  12477 7949 7550 7668 9891  |  45535
```

Take a look at the structure, implement your 2D array as needed (since you will want it to group 20 lines, declaring it within the `for` loop scope and initializing it there will reset it for each group). If you run into problems, just let me know. It may seem like a lot at first, if you just break it down into pieces (line, group, file, etc...) and build from the line (where you take input) out, it will help it fall into place.